# Latest version of Ubuntu Won't login to GUI

Tags: ubuntu, unity

I'm assuming this is an issue with UNITY because I can log in just fine at the command line. When I boot up my most recent kernel, I enter valid credentials but It just keeps kicking me back to the prompt. If I boot up a previous kernel I don't have an issue. I haven't had much luck finding any similar cases. How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: The first step is to check, and preferably post here, your `~/.xsession-errors` file. Next step will be checking `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: If you haven't had much luck, then you've been looking in the wrong place.  AskUbuntu has similar cases coming out of its ears, including: http://askubuntu.com/questions/614128/ http://askubuntu.com/questions/612973/ http://askubuntu.com/questions/613577/ http://askubuntu.com/questions/610654/ http://askubuntu.com/questions/613239/ http://askubuntu.com/questions/613698/

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. I was looking in the wrong places apparently. I will try these suggestions later and post my solution.